# Create chart in tooltip formatter

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I tried to create a  inside formatter[of tooltip config] inside which I was trying to create a chart dynamically but failed to acheive so. Any bright ideas?

Comment: you said you have tried something. can please put it in a jsfiddle and post it here. that would help us give you a solution if you have gone wrong somewhere,

Comment: I didn't know where to start with :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create new container inside tooltip `formatter`, and there also create new chart. Important part is to create chart **after** tooltip is rendered. For example use `setTimeout`. Also, `useHTML: true` is required, so `formatter` will return HTML elements, not SVG.

See working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EtvMR/4/

Of course, you will need to get some data according to hovered point, but in example I'm using static data.

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function() {
            setTimeout( function() {
                $("#hc-tooltip").highcharts({
                    series: [{
                        data: [12, 12]
                    }]
                });
            }, 10)

            return '<div id="hc-tooltip"></div>';
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        data: [29.9, 71.5]
    }]
});
```